# Ошибка LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static class GLFWwindow * Window::window"

Tags: c++, ооп, opengl, glfw

Ошибка  LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static class GLFWwindow * Window::window"
Мучаюсь с єтой ошибкой пол дня. Суть ошибка візвана изза использования статического поля класса.
код:

**Window.h**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Window.cpp**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом есть еще класс Евентс а в нём статический метод Инициализации и там при созданиии переменной вылазит эта ошибка

**Events.cpp**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если убрать строки

```
GLFWwindow *window = Window::window;
```

и

```
 glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursor_position_callback);
```

то всё работает но их убирать нельзя по функционалу программы

Помогите пожалуйста П.С. Все библиотеки подключены проверил 100 раз. Искал такие же вопросы там у ним проблема решалась тем что они обьявили статический член класса ,а ведь у меня он тоже определён в виндов.спп , Перерыл кучу вопросов ни один не помог . Код взят с этого видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ihn-9EYWOEs& с разницей в пару символов ИДЕ- визуал студия

Полный код:

main.cpp

```
    #include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#define GLEW_STATIC

#include "Window.h"
#include "Events.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "glew32.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "glfw3.lib" )
#pragma comment (lib, "OpenGL32.lib")

int width = 800;
int height = 600;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Window::initialize(width,height,"3D engine");   
    Events::initialize();
    while (!Window::isShoudeClose())
    {
        Events::pullEvents();
        if (Events::JustPressed(GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE))
        {
            Window::ShoudeClose(); 
        }
        Window::SwapBuffer();
    }
    Window::terminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Window.h

```
#pragma once

class GLFWwindow;

class Window
{
public:
    static GLFWwindow* window ;

    static int initialize(int, int , const char* );
    static void terminate();
    static bool isShoudeClose();
    static void ShoudeClose();
    static void SwapBuffer();
};
```

window.cpp

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw3.h>
#include "Window.h"

GLFWwindow* Window::window;

int Window::initialize(int w, int h, const char* title)
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
        
    window = glfwCreateWindow(w, h, title, nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (window == nullptr)
        return -1;
    
    if (glewInit() == GLEW_OK)
        return -2;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    return 0;
}
 bool Window::isShoudeClose() 
 {
     return glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
 }
 void Window::ShoudeClose()
 {
     glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, 1);
 }
 void Window::SwapBuffer()
 {
     glfwSwapBuffers(window);
 }
 void Window::terminate() 
 {
     glfwTerminate();
 }
```

Events.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Window.h"

class Events
{
public:

    static bool* _keys;
    static unsigned int* _frames;
    static unsigned int _curr;
    static float deltaX;
    static float deltaY;
    static float x;
    static float y;
    static bool _cursor_locked;
    static bool _cursor_started;

    static int initialize();
    static void pullEvents();

    static bool Pressed(int keycode);
    static bool JustPressed(int keycode);
};
```

Events.cpp

```
#include "Events.h"
#include <glfw3.h>
#include <string.h>

bool* Events::_keys;
unsigned int* Events::_frames;
unsigned int Events::_curr = 0;
float Events::deltaX = 0.0f;
float Events::deltaY = 0.0f;
float Events::x = 0.0f;
float Events::y = 0.0f;
bool Events::_cursor_locked = 0;
bool Events::_cursor_started = 0;


void cursor_position_callback(GLFWwindow* win, double posX, double posY)
{
    if (Events::_cursor_locked)
    {
        Events::deltaX += posX - Events::x;
        Events::deltaY += posY - Events::y;
    }
    else 
    {
        Events::_cursor_started = 1;
    }
    Events::x = posX;
    Events::y = posY;

}

#define _MOUSE_BUTTON 1024
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* win, int button, int action, int mode)
{
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        Events::_keys[_MOUSE_BUTTON + button] = 1;
        Events::_frames[_MOUSE_BUTTON + button] = Events::_curr;
    }
    else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE) 
    {
        Events::_keys[_MOUSE_BUTTON + button] = 0;
        Events::_frames[_MOUSE_BUTTON + button] = Events::_curr;
    }
}

void key_callback(GLFWwindow* win, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        Events::_keys[key] = 1;
        Events::_frames[key] = Events::_curr;
    }
    else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE) 
    {
        Events::_keys[key] = 0;
        Events::_frames[key] = Events::_curr;
    }
}

int Events::initialize()
{
    GLFWwindow *window = Window::window;
    _keys = new bool[1032];
    _frames = new unsigned int[1032];

    memset(_keys, 0, 1032*sizeof(bool));
    memset(_frames, 0, 1032 * sizeof(unsigned int));
    
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, cursor_position_callback);
    return 0;
}

bool Events::Pressed(int keycode)
{
    if (keycode < 0 || keycode > _MOUSE_BUTTON)
        return false;
    return _keys[keycode];
}
bool Events::JustPressed(int keycode)
{
    if (keycode < 0 || keycode > _MOUSE_BUTTON)
        return false;
    return _keys[keycode] && _frames[keycode] == _curr;
}


void Events::pullEvents()
{
    _curr++;
    deltaX = 0.0f;
    deltaY = 0.0f;
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Полные ошибки

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: Bender, Конфигурация: Debug x64 ------
1>Events.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "public: static class GLFWwindow * Window::window" (?window@Window@@2PEAVGLFWwindow@@EA).
1>C:\Users\muzyk\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Cpp_projects\bender\Bender\x64\Debug\Bender.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
1>Сборка проекта "Bender.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Comment: Тебе нужно инициализировать static переменную...

Comment: нет не дубликат я тот вопрос читал не помогло

Comment: если обьявляю как статик переменную класа Евентс всеравно не помогает

Comment: Скопируйте код текстом в вопрос! Приведите полный текст ошибки из окна вывода.

Comment: сделал полный код и ошибку

Comment: Удалите то что вы написали ошибки, и приводите ошибки из **окна вывода**, не из окна с ошибкой, там будет указано место проблемное. Если у вас нет такого окна, перейдите в вид, другие окна, вывод.

Comment: изменил теперь ошибка вывода

Comment: Отлично, а теперь удалите пробел после объявления переменной `window`, перед точкой с запятой, и попробуйте собрать снова.

Comment: о каком пробеле идет речь? Если тот что в Виндов.аш то его убрал не помогло

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117959/discussion-between-mik-ov-and-albion-muz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найденное решение спустя некоторое время, не знаю как, но не обратил внимания на то что структура была написана как класс в forward declaration, и компилятор пытался найти именно класс. Насколько я помню, то при наследовании можно менять `class <-> struct` но не при forward declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Тема уже наверное закрыта, но я сам недавно столкнулся с такой проблемой и пришлось искать ответ, по выбраному ответу понял что проблема в классе но каком сразу было не понятно. Ответ пишу для тех кто может когда то тоже столкнутся с такой проблемой в файле "Window.h"
Нужно изменить:
`class GFLWwindow;`
на:
`struct GLFWwindow;`